# Remove locale specific punctuation in Java

Tags: java, string, icu, punctuation

What is the best way to remove punctuation from a String given a specific locale?
eg a String in Japanese or Spanish might have a different set of punctuation marks to remove.

I understand this 1-liner is English locale only:
`s = s.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "");`

Comment: Try `"\\p{P}"` which should be the [unicode category](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) for punctuation.

Comment: That does not remove non "C locale" punctuation marks. For example, it didn't catch the Spanish question mark - ¿

Comment: Well, in my tests it did: `"A.B.C.¿Quién?どこから来たの？".replaceAll("\\p{P}", "")` resulted in `"ABCQuiénどこから来たの"`. Which Java version or regex engine are you using?

Answer (score 0):

What symbol a punctuation is nor not does not depend on the locale, thats why you can not give a locale as a parameter to the method `replaceAll`.